# Extracting / printing slider value when button is clicked in matplotlib widget (Python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, slider, matplotlib-widget

I am using the template for the Matplotlib slider widget. I am using [this](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/widgets/slider_demo.html) template. How can I alter the script under the "Reset" button to print out the value of the Amp and Freq sliders?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons

ax = plt.subplot(111)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)
a0 = 5
f0 = 3
s = a0*np.sin(2*np.pi*f0*t)
l, = plt.plot(t,s, lw=2, color='red')
plt.axis([0, 1, -10, 10])

axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axfreq = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)
axamp  = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)

sfreq = Slider(axfreq, 'Freq', 0.1, 30.0, valinit=f0)
samp = Slider(axamp, 'Amp', 0.1, 10.0, valinit=a0)

def update(val):
    amp = samp.val
    freq = sfreq.val
    l.set_ydata(amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t))
    plt.draw()
sfreq.on_changed(update)
samp.on_changed(update)

resetax = plt.axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(resetax, 'Reset', color=axcolor, hovercolor='0.975')

def reset(event):
    sfreq.reset()
    samp.reset()
button.on_clicked(reset)

rax = plt.axes([0.025, 0.5, 0.15, 0.15], axisbg=axcolor)
radio = RadioButtons(rax, ('red', 'blue', 'green'), active=0)
def colorfunc(label):
    l.set_color(label)
    plt.draw()
radio.on_clicked(colorfunc)

plt.show()
```

Comment: It seems that this is only part of the code. Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: The majority of the code was included in the link that was given. Regardless, I've edited the question to avoid confusion. This should be more clear.

Comment: This adds a little more confusion, since there is no `print`statement anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code above replace the `reset` function by something like

```
def reset(event):
    print "Amplitude: ",  samp.val
    #sfreq.reset()
    #samp.reset()
```